# 3 Monitors powered from a Nvidia fx580

Tags: dvi, vga, displayport

I have a NVidia FX580 card in a Dell Precision T1500.

The outputs of the back of the card are DVI and 2x displayport.

I tried to run 3 screens from the DVI + 2x displayport to dvi adaptors, but the card won't have it... It'll only run 2 of these screens at the same time.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_fx_580_us.html says;

```
**Display Support:**
Dual Link DVI-I      1
DisplayPort          2
# of Digital Outputs    3
                        ( 2 out of 3 active at a time )
# of Analog Outputs  1
```

To me this reads that it will be able to power 2xdvi monitors and 1xvga monitor.
Anyone care to confirm or speculate?

Comment: I also have same graphics card inside dell precision T3500. My question - what is the cheapest graphics card that will support 3 monitors, be compatible with my dell precision T3500, and have at least as much performance as the quadro fx580?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DVI port supports DVI-I (digital) or DVI-A (analog), so it's counted in both *Outputs* categories.  The card only supports 2 outputs in use at a time.

Comment: Whats the point of the card having 3 connectors on the back then? For people that have monitors with displayport connectors and that want to ignore the dvi connector???

Comment: it gives you the option of using DVI or DisplayPort for one of the connections.  this is fairly common -- a GPU only supporting two simultaneous outputs but the card or motherboard provides several connectors.  my most recent build uses an Nvidia ION board that provides VGA, DVI, and HDMI, but the GPU only supports 2 simultaneous outputs.  i get to choose which 2 i want to use.