# Quadro FX580: DVI->VGA + 2 DisplayPort->DVI (3 screens?)

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

Have a FX580 that has 1x DVI & 2x DisplayPort

I've got 3 screen hooked up as so:

- DVI Port:  DVI-to-VGA to Screen 1
- DisplayPort 1: DP-to-DVI to Screen 2
- DisplayPort 2: DP-to-DVI to Screen 3

However I can only seem to get 2 screens active at one time in the nVidia control panel.

Seems I should be able to get 3 active since it's just an analog VGA signal going to the DVI port, and both TMDS channels should be routed to the DP ports.  (And I've confirmed that both TMDS channels can be routed to DP, as those 2 screens can be active simultaneousnesly)

(The control panel is detecting my VGA monitor as "DVI", but this is not correct.  It's VGA on the DVI pass-through pins.)

Any way to get all 3 active at the same time with out an active DP-DVI adapter?

Thanks,
:)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/122729/3-monitors-powered-from-a-nvidia-fx580.  This information is accurate (I've tested this card myself).  You might consider a FirePro if you need a card like that that will light three - I know I've tested the V4800 myself and it works great (and is appreciably faster than the FX580 in our benchmarks to boot)

Comment: Thanks.  Does anyone know the technical reason this can not work? Is it just a software issue, or is it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  The card is limited internally to two displays.